# C# Download all https certificates from a website

Tags: c#, ssl, server, certificate, x509certificate

I want to save all certificates from a URL to disk. So for example *https://www.google.de*

If I browse this page with Firefox, I can see three certificates.
[image]

With Firefox I can export them all, and save them to disk.

So I want to do that in C#.
I started getting the certificates with the following code..

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and write certificate from URL into file in path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_URL">URL of website with certficate</param>
    /// <param name="_path">Path where you want to store certificate</param>
    private static void SaveCertificate(String _URL, String _path)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_URL);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(request.ServicePoint.Certificate);

            File.WriteAllText(_path, ExportToPEM(cert));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Export a certificate to a PEM format string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_cert">The certificate to export</param>
    /// <returns>A PEM encoded string</returns>
    public static string ExportToPEM(X509Certificate2 _cert)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
            builder.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(_cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
            builder.AppendLine("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

The problem with this code is, I just get one certificate exept three. (the certificate I get is the marked certificate in the screenshot from firefox)

I also tryed the solution from here [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618798/automated-downloading-of-x509-certificate-chain-from-remote-host) but it didnt work for me.

My question is, how can I get all certificates from a URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way you can get the certificate chain is by implementing a `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` on your `request`.

It's a function that accepts the parameters:

`(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)`

This is normally used to validate the certificate and chain, but in this case we're just using it to get access to the certificate chain. It *does* feel a lot like a hack but it should work. I've implemented an proof of concept based on your posted code. The code outputs the certs to the console window.

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SaveCertificate("https://www.google.de", "");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and write certificate from URL into file in path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_URL">URL of website with certficate</param>
    /// <param name="_path">Path where you want to store certificate</param>
    private static void SaveCertificate(string url, string path)
    {

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        foreach (var cer in chain.ChainElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cer.Certificate.FriendlyName);
            Console.WriteLine(ExportToPem(cer.Certificate));
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Export a certificate to a PEM format string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_cert">The certificate to export</param>
    /// <returns>A PEM encoded string</returns>
    public static string ExportToPem(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
            builder.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
            builder.AppendLine("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```